# OpenSCAD parser error in the *middle* of a comment when last line accidentally uncommented?

Tags: error-handling, openscad

I have the following segment of comment in my code file (the last line is intentionally missing the slash characters - that the error):

```
// * Cube Back Text from Méi guī
// 一颗 心 怕 摔倒 打破
//"yī kē xīn  pà shuāi dǎo  dǎ pò"
// "It's the heart afraid of breaking"
// 不敢 起舞 欢 歌
// "bù gǎn  qǐwǔ huāngē"
// "that never learns to dance."

不敢起舞欢歌              (dance)
```

But the red error dot appears on the second character of the second line (second slash of the line `"// * Cube Back Text from Méi guī"`.

Stranger, if I remove various quotes in the comment, the character that is hilited changes.

I assume this has something to do with a recursive structure somewhere in the parser that is continuing to parse the quotes *inside the comment itself* and ultimately figures out where to signal the error.

I suppose this is a bug ("semi-bug") that I should post to the GitHub list - to completely ignore *anything* past the second slash on a commented line, or some other change so that the error tag shows up on the line where the error actually is?

As it is, I futzed around about 10 minutes wondering if OpenSCAD just didn't like files longer than 575 lines.

Comment: The asterisk after the slash probably creates some nasty nested comment structure

Comment: What version of OpenSCAD are you on?  I am unable to reproduce the problem on 2021.01.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when I try your example or modify it slightly but it worked perfectly when I replaced everything with random Latin characters so I think the bug has a lot to do with the Chinese ideographs you used.

In any case, I only copied the small sample you gave so it probably have nothing to do with the length of the file.